# PI controller ringing once deadband hit

Tags: power-supply, pic, control-system, pid-controller, code

I am controlling a power supply with a home-brewed PCB. The power supply has some weird drift, so I implemented a PI controller in software to reel it in, but the output voltage rings once the dead band is hit. Is this a known issue?

edit: iErrorFlag is a counter that is incremented by a 100ms timer

I tried turning the controller off once the deadband has been reached but that didn't help.

[image: Image of what do]

```
while (1) {
  // Endless loop to sample the Isense and Vsense meanwhile listen to UART RX line whether a command arrived
            
  // Acquire Current Reading if Flag set by Timer4.
  if (fLTCRead == 1) {
    Read_LTC4151(); // Call read for current measurement from LTC4151
    fLTCRead = 0; // Clear Flag to Read LTC4151 Data
  }
            
  if (!VSENSE_TRIG && !VSENSE_READY) {
    // Manually Triggers Sample Collection
    VSENSE_TRIG = HIGH;
  };
            
  // Assigns Voltage Reading from Digital Filter 0 if new reading available.
  valueV = (VSENSE_READY) ? VSENSE_SRC : valueV;
            
  // Converts the 12-bit voltage value into volts
  vCommon = (float)valueV * LV_CONVERT;
            
  // This corrects the voltage seen on the computer to multimeter readings 
  // at the white switch board, and converts the voltage back to 12-bit.
  // correction factor is function of current x*A + y
  CORRECTION_FACTOR = vDepen*current + offset;

  correctedV = vCommon + CORRECTION_FACTOR; 
 
  controlled = piControl(correctedV, vSet, .1);

  if (controlCounter == 5) { // 20 = 1s
    temp1 = (unsigned int)(controlled / LV_CONVERT);
    changeInBuff(temp1);
    fCMD = 1;
    controlCounter = 0;
  }
            
  // Handle LTC4151 Current Data
  Update_Current();
            
  // Update Stack Lights
  Update_StackLights();
            
  receiveCommand();
            
  Process_CMD();
} // While

float piControl(float measured, float set, float max_error) {
  float p = 1.1; //95
  float i = .34; //34
  float temp = 0.0;
  float error = 0.0;
        
  // if we have reached the deadband stop doing things
  // if (measured < (set+max_error)) {
  //   if (measured > (set-max_error)) {
  //     return measured;
  //   }
  // }
        
  error = set - measured; // note the error
  if (iErrorFlag == 20) { // 10 = 1s
     errorAcum = errorAcum + error; // error accumulation
     iErrorFlag = 0; // reset counter
  }
        
  temp = measured;
  // if not in deadband move torwards it
  if (fabs((double)error) >= max_error) {
    temp = temp + error*p + errorAcum*i; // augment with PI error control
    error = temp - set; // recalculate error
    // do not reset errorAcum
  }
        
  return temp;
}
```

edit:
This is what i think im understanding from the comments so far, I added limits to the error accumulation to help with wind up

```
float piControl(float measured, float set, float max_error)
{
    float p = .95; //95 //1.1
    float i = .34; //34
    float temp = 0.0;
    float error = 0.0;
    
    error = set - measured; // note the error
    
    if (iErrorFlag == 1) // 10 = 1s
    {
        errorAcum = errorAcum + error; // error accumulation
        iErrorFlag = 0;                // reset counter
    }
    
    if(errorAcum >= 10.0){errorAcum = 10.0;}
    if(errorAcum <= -10.0){errorAcum = -10.0;}
    
    temp = measured;
    if (fabs((double)error) >= max_error)
    {
        temp = temp + error*p + errorAcum*i; // might have to change ki relative to error accumulation time
    }
    else
    {
        temp = temp + error*p;
    }
    
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Please _edit your question_ so that it states how and when do you update `iErrorFlag`, and the timescale of your graph.

Comment: So if the value is inside the deadband then you just return measured and don't apply any feedback at all?

Comment: @TimWescott i edited my original post. iErrorFlag is a counter that is incremented by a 100ms timer

Comment: @user253751 yes that is what im attempting

Comment: So when the signal is outside the deadband, I suppose that you are applying some feedback, perhaps a very large feedback to move it towards the deadband, but then as soon as the signal touches the deadband, you turn that feedback off and the signal  goes back to whatever it was previously doing. Can you chart the feedback as well as the signal?

Comment: @user253751I currently cannot with the tools i am using but i think i can write something up for it and get back to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What a PI controller *should* be is something like

$$y_n = k_p (u_n - x_n) + k_i \sum_{m = 0}^n (u_m - x_m). \tag 1$$

I.e, not complicated (except you should look up "integrator anti-windup" and implement it).

Assuming that your `iErrorFlag == 20` always returns true and you didn't have your deadband behavior masked off by commenting out code, then *your* controller is

$$y_n = \begin{cases}
k_p (u_n - x_n) + \sum_{m = 0}^n (u_m - x_m) & \mathrm{\overline{deadband}} \\
x_n & \mathrm{deadband}
\end{cases}. \tag 2$$

That second case -- doesn't make sense.  And the action around `iErrorFlag`, which I assume means "only integrate every 20th sample of the error" also doesn't make much sense.

---

Your second code listing is better, except that (A) you're trying to apply two different and separate anti-windup measures where you want to choose just one and run with it, and (B) you appear to be attempting to apply anti-windup when you shouldn't, and not applying it when you should.

First, (B): `if (fabs((double)error) >= max_error)` means that you will apply integral action when the error is **large**.  Generally, if you use anti-windup that turns integration action off at certain times, that turn-off is done when the error is large, not when it is small.  The *whole and entire point* of integral action is to drive the average error to zero -- that can't be done when it's turned off.

Even if you did reverse the sense of the `if` statement (i.e., change it to `if (fabs((double)error) < max_error)`), then the integrator would still be integrating when it's not being used.  **This is bad**: during that time of high error and no integral action actually being applied, the integrator will build up to some high value; suddenly using it will essentially inject a large random drive into the system.

**If** you use the method where you turn off integral action when the error is high, you should not *not accumulate error* into the integrator.

Second, (A): choose one and stick with it.  Different integrator windup schemes are good in different circumstances.  The one where you limit the integrator state is good when you have a process that's servoed, or one where proportional gain alone won't get your error into a predictable range -- and you need that predictable range to know when to turn on integral action.  The one where you turn on integration is pretty much the obverse -- it's good for starting up a regulator, or a servo that never has large swings on the input command.

If you *do* use the method of only integrating when the error is small, then you should *always* have these lines active:

```
temp = measured;
temp = temp + error * p + errorAcum * i;
```

You should control the integrator action like this:

```
if (fabs((double)error) >= max_error)
{
    errorAcum = 0;
}
else
{
    errorAcum += error;
}
```

Note that if your error goes below the maximum for a while and then escapes those bounds there'll be a step change in the drive -- this is why you don't want to use this technique where that may happen (and trying to make more elaborate ways of managing the mode change just makes for control engineers needing bed rest and medications).

Comment: what do you mean by masking off the deadband? also isnt the integral control supposed to run on a certain period?

Comment: Integral control should be _updated_ on a certain period, but it shouldn't run for a finite amount of time and stop.

Comment: I dont think im understanding the difference between updating and running. Do you mean updating the error accumulation and running the actual "+errorAcum*ki" or vise versa?

Comment: We're going beyond your original question.  Read [this](https://wescottdesign.com/articles/pid/pidWithoutAPhd.pdf).  While it's my work, it's just a distillation of what everyone does, not something dramatic and unique.  The salient point to integration is that, like everything else, *you do it every sample*, not just every once in a while.

Comment: TimWescott... (wouldnt let me @ you) Would you be willing to look at my updated code in the edit above and see if im picking up what youre putting down? The paper was insightful but in the case of PI control i wish there was a code example.

Comment: @thunderbootyclap - Hi, Please see [this article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) about `@replies` in comments. It explains that the author of a Q or A is always notified of comments on that Q or A. Also if there is only one other user in a comment thread (as was the case here, before I commented) then since it is clear who any comments must be aimed at, they also get notified automatically, meaning you don't need to (and can't) `@` notify them.

Comment: @SamGibson Ohhh ok sorry bout that i hadnt noticed

Comment: @thunderbootyclap - Hi, No need to apologise :) Although the site behaviour is explained in that article, IMHO it is a bit unintuitive - so I wanted to give you the official info so you can read it yourself.